# GTK 2 Ctrl-Z accelerator does not trigger

Tags: c, keyboard-shortcuts, gtk2

I'm building a simple app with GTK+ 2 and I have a typical "Edit" menu with the items; Undo, Redo, Cut, Copy & Paste. I create my Edit menu like this (apologies for verbosity):

```
GtkWidget* get_editmenu(GtkWidget *window)
{
  GtkWidget
    *menu,
    *menuitem,
    *item
  ;
  GtkAccelGroup *group;

  menu = gtk_menu_new();
  group = gtk_accel_group_new();

  gtk_menu_set_accel_group(GTK_MENU(menu), group);
  gtk_window_add_accel_group(GTK_WINDOW(window), group);

  menuitem = gtk_menu_item_new_with_label("Edit");
  gtk_menu_item_set_submenu(GTK_MENU_ITEM(menuitem), menu);

  item = gtk_image_menu_item_new_from_stock(GTK_STOCK_UNDO, group);
  g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(item), "activate", G_CALLBACK(on_undo), NULL);
  gtk_menu_shell_append(GTK_MENU_SHELL(menu), item);

  item = gtk_image_menu_item_new_from_stock(GTK_STOCK_REDO, group);
  g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(item), "activate", G_CALLBACK(on_redo), NULL);
  gtk_menu_shell_append(GTK_MENU_SHELL(menu), item);

  gtk_menu_shell_append(GTK_MENU_SHELL(menu), gtk_separator_menu_item_new());

  item = gtk_image_menu_item_new_from_stock(GTK_STOCK_COPY, group);
  g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(item), "activate", G_CALLBACK(on_copy), NULL);
  gtk_menu_shell_append(GTK_MENU_SHELL(menu), item);

  item = gtk_image_menu_item_new_from_stock(GTK_STOCK_CUT, group);
  g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(item), "activate", G_CALLBACK(on_cut), NULL);
  gtk_menu_shell_append(GTK_MENU_SHELL(menu), item);

  item = gtk_image_menu_item_new_from_stock(GTK_STOCK_PASTE, group);
  g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(item), "activate", G_CALLBACK(on_paste), NULL);
  gtk_menu_shell_append(GTK_MENU_SHELL(menu), item);

  return menuitem;
}
```

This function simply returns the top level menu item (i.e. the "Edit" item) which is then added to my menu bar:

```
GtkWidget* get_menubar(GtkWidget *window)
{
  GtkWidget *menubar;

  menubar = gtk_menu_bar_new();

  gtk_menu_shell_append(GTK_MENU_SHELL(menubar), get_filemenu(window));
  gtk_menu_shell_append(GTK_MENU_SHELL(menubar), get_editmenu(window));
  gtk_menu_shell_append(GTK_MENU_SHELL(menubar), get_helpmenu(window));

  return menubar;
}
```

This works great. My accelerators are working for Ctrl+O (open file), Ctrl+Q (the quit the app), Ctrl+C (copy), etc.. However, Doing Ctrl+Z doesn't trigger the Undo callback, neither does Ctrl+Shift+Z for Redo. When I trigger them manually by opening the Edit menu and selecting them though a click, my callbacks are triggered just fine.

How can I activate the Undo and Redo items by using Ctrl+Z and Ctrl+Shift+Z?

Comment: `undo/redo` are not provided by Gtk, they are provided by GtkSourceView. (you can use GtkSourceView2 -- the html manual is included in the tarball or you can look at the GtkSourceView4 pages online -- [GtkSourceView 4 Reference Manual](https://developer.gnome.org/gtksourceview/stable/)) I have two projects that use Ver. 2 [GtkWrite](https://github.com/drankinatty/gtkwrite) and [GtKate](https://github.com/drankinatty/gtkate) (in initial development). To use without GtkSourceView -- you have to write your own undo/redo handler (not for the faint of heart)

Comment: The specific commands providing `undo` are `if (gtk_source_buffer_can_undo (buffer)) gtk_source_buffer_undo (buffer);` and you have a matching pair for `redo`.